# application.run vba not working with sheet macros

Tags: vba, excel

My file has different sheets with the same-named sub routine inside each doing different things specific to the sheet. So, I'm trying to call dynamically a macro inside a selected sheet using `Application.Run` from a module. All sheets' "object" name (I don't know how to call those) are already modified to be the same as its view (inside the bracket) name, without the spaces.

```
macro = Chr(39) & ThisWorkbook.Name & Chr(39) & "!" & Replace(SheetName, " ", "") & "." & "Harmoniser()"
Application.Run macro
```

Here's an example of the `Harmoniser` macro in a Sheet.

```
Sub Harmoniser()
    ActiveSheet.Range("k22").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("l13")
    MsgBox ("Done!")
End Sub
```

Somehow, only the `MsgBox` works, and it shows it twice everytime. Debugging by putting a break point doesn't work either. It happens to all of my sheets. Is there a limitation to Application.Run that it only allows certain code or there's an error that Excel is not giving me?

Comment: Remove the () from the macro name and it will cure both problems. :) The code assumes the correct sheet is active - you probably want `Me.Range("K22")...` in the sheet code.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same thing when I run your code. I tried a few different tweaks and am able to enter debug/breakpoint mode if I do this:

```
Sub t()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim macro As String

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Activate
    macro = sht.CodeName & ".Harmoniser"
    Application.Run macro
Next
End Sub
```

Your code may have been erroring silently because you were using `ActiveSheet` without first *Activating* the sheet which contains the macro to be run. Not sure about the double-display of the MsgBox, but seems like that may be related.